# DirectX Car and world moving together

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to create simple movement for my car model using directX11, which i have done like this:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
eyex += 0.05f;

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
eyex -= 0.05f;

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
//eyenew += (eyey + 0.05f);
eyey += 0.05f;


if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
eyey -= 0.05f;

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ADD))
eyez += 0.05f;

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DIVIDE))
eyez -= 0.05f;

XMFLOAT4 nEw = XMFLOAT4(eyex, eyey, eyez, 0.0f);
Car->SetTranslation(nEw.x, nEw.y, nEw.z);
Car->UpdateWorld();

XMFLOAT4 Eye = XMFLOAT4(eye1, eye2, eye3, 0.0f);
XMFLOAT4 At = XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMFLOAT4 Up = XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
mCam->SetEye(Eye);
mCam->CalculateViewProjection();
```

The car moves, as i intended but so does the ground plane. I don't understand, as i'm not referencing the Ground plane in the translation. What could the problem be?

Comment: Are you sure you don't do anything to the camera? What does mCam->SetEye(Eye)  do?

Comment: it returns a 4d vector used in the view matrix. void SetEye(XMFLOAT4 eye) { _eye = eye; }

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, i forgot to make a new world matrix local to the Plane.